# Enforce immutability or partial immutability that doesn't fail silently

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutability

Is there a way to enforce partial immutability on an object that will throw an error if someone tries to mutate it?

For example, `let obj = {a: 1, b: 2}` and I want `obj.a` and `obj.b` to be immutable but to still allow more keys to be added to obj, i.e to allow `obj.c = 3`.

I thought of nesting properties in sub-objects and using `Object.freeze` like so:

```
let obj = {subObj:{a: 1, b:2}}; 
Object.freeze(obj.subObj);
```

But it appears that it fails silently afterward, i.e `obj.subObj.a = 3` doesn't mutate `a` but doesn't give any indication of a problem either. Is there a way to force it to throw an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to do this would be with getters that return static values and 
setters that throw errors.

```js
let obj = {
  get a() {
    return 1;
  },
  set a(val) {
    throw new Error('Can\'t set a');
  },
  get b() {
    return 2;
  },
  set b(val) {
    throw new Error('Can\'t set b');
  }
};
obj.c = 3; // works
console.log(obj);
obj.a = 4; // throws an error
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.defineProperties()` with `writable` set to `false` for properties `"a"` and  `"b"`, `"use strict"`, `try..catch..finally`

```js
"use strict";

let obj = new Object;

Object.defineProperties(obj, {
  "a": {value:1, writable: false},
  "b": {value:2, writable: false}
});

try {
  obj.c = 3;
  obj.a = 3;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
} finally {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: Is this js reflection?

Comment: What do you mean by "js reflection"?

Comment: I meant just reflection, drop the "js".

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Add the following the beginning of your file:

```
'use strict'
```

It will throw exception if u will modify your object after freeze.